# Is it possible to keep track of the state when processing logs by DataFlow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is it possible to have the DataFlow process maintain the state.  There are log processing tools that allow for that by providing fast access (propriety / in-memory) files available for the real time process to keep track of the state on the logs while processing them.
A use case example would be with tracking registration steps taken by users. The registration steps would come in different logs and the data form those logs would be assembled by the real time process into one final database record (for each registered user) that is written to a database.
Can my DataFLow code keep track of the many registration steps (streaming input) by users and once  user's registration steps are completed then have the DataFLow process write the records to the database (one record per user).

I don't know much about DataFlow architecture.  It must be using some (proprietary / in-memory nosql) data storage for keeping track of things it needs to keep track of (ex. when it tries to produce top 100 customers).   Is that fast access data storage also available to the DataFlow processes to use?

Thanks

Comment: very unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

As danielm said, state is not yet exposed. The good news is you may not need it for your use case.

If you have a `PCollection<KV<UserId, LogEvent>>` you can use a `CombineFn` and `Combine.perKey` to take all of the `LogEvent`s for a specific `UserId` and combine them into a single output. The `CombineFn` tells Dataflow how to create an accumulator, update it by incorporating input elements, and then extract a final output. Transforms like `Top` actually use a `CombineFn` (with a Heap as the accumulator) rather than an actual state API.

If your events are of different types, you can still do something like this. For instance, if you have two logs, you can do:

```
PCollection<KV<UserId, LogEvent1>> events1 = ...;
PCollection<KV<UserId, LogEvent2>> events2 = ...;

// Create tuple tags for the value types in each collection.
final TupleTag<LogEvent1> tag1 = new TupleTag<LogEvent1>();
final TupleTag<LogEvent2> tag2 = new TupleTag<LogEvent2>();

 //Merge collection values into a CoGbkResult collection
PCollection<KV<UserIf, CoGbkResult>> coGbkResultCollection =
KeyedPCollectionTuple.of(tag1, pt1)
                     .and(tag2, pt2)
                     .apply(CoGroupByKey.<UserId>create());

// Access results and do something.
PCollection<T> finalResultCollection =
  coGbkResultCollection.apply(ParDo.of(
    new DoFn<KV<K, CoGbkResult>, T>() {
      @Override
      public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        KV<K, CoGbkResult> e = c.element();
        // Get all LogEvent1 values
        Iterable<LogEvent1> event1s = e.getValue().getAll(tag1);
        // There will only be one LogEvent2
        LogEvent2 event2 = e.getValue().getOnly(tag2);
        ... Do Something to compute T ....
        c.output(...some T...);
      }
    }));
```

The above example was adapted from [docs on CoGroupByKey](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/group-by-key#join) which have information.

Answer (score 2):

Dataflow does not currently expose the underlying state mechanism that it uses.  However, this is definitely on the radar for a future update.